# ErrorException: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, migration

I cloned a laravel project and ran `composer install` but when I run `php artisan migrate` it gives me :

```
 [ErrorException]                          
 Creating default object from empty value
```

what does this exception means ? and how to solve it please ?

Comment: check if you mentioned the table name in the migration file.

Answer (score 0):

**Massive guess** because you haven't given us much to work on, but I would say in one of your migration files, you have something like:

```
$table->string('le_field')->default();
```

Which should be instead:

```
$table->string('le_field')->default('le default value');
```

Comment: I verified and there is no `$table->string('le_field')->default()`

Comment: Have you made any changes to the migration files?

Comment: No I didn't I just cloned the project and edited the .env file to set the database name and the user name